# Setting up word2vec - KeyError: "word 'word' not in vocabulary"

Tags: python, character-encoding, gensim, word2vec

I try to use word2vec, but it gives an error when trying to do anything with any word. It seems to be an encoding issue, here is what I did:

#### Init word2vec:

```
import gensim, logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('freebase-vectors-skipgram1000/knowledge-vectors-skipgram1000.bin', binary=True)
model.init_sims(replace=True)
```

#### Test it a bit:

```
print(model)  
# prints: Word2Vec(vocab=1422903, size=1000, alpha=0.025)

print(model.index2word[0])  
# prints: u'/m/0dgps15'
# I would expect a readable word, how to fix that?
```

#### The error:

```
print(model.similarity('word', 'sound'))
# An error happen: KeyError: 'word'
```

I also tried to load the model with `binary=False`, but this makes an error while loading.

Comment: I see that you have unaccepted the answer? Are you facing some issue?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with your word2vec usage. File format is binary (and can be converted to text using [this nice utility](https://github.com/marekrei/convertvec)).

You have downloaded a pre-trained "entity" vector file. I'll recommend you to use word or phrase vectors (also available on word2vec website) from [Google News](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYNlNUTTlSS21pQmM/).

```
[1] import gensim
[2] model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
[3] print(model.similarity('word', 'sound'))
0.152615140536
```